# Error: The project output folder is being used by a Service Fabric application

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-service-fabric

When I compile solution that contains 16 Service Fabric applications, Visual Studio hangs on several of them (2 or 3) from time to time.

Message in Error List:

```
The project output folder is being used by a Service Fabric application. The fabric application didn't release the lock on the output folder within 00:02:00 minutes.
```

Text in Output Window:

```
Build started 8/31/2017 11:11:20 AM.
_WaitForServiceFabricApplicationCleanupBeforeBuild:
Waiting for output folder cleanup...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Service Fabric Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ServiceProject.targets(28,5): error : The project output folder is being used by a Service Fabric application. The fabric application didn't release the lock on the output folder within 00:02:00 minutes.

Build FAILED.
```

I understand that the reason is connected with Local Cluster but it's important tool and I want to continue to use.

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric 5.6.220.9494

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK 2.6.220.9494

Local Cluster works in 1-Node mode.

Answer (score 3):

As workaround to resolve this issue you can try to build project using only one thread. In Visual Studio go to

Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> Build and Run

and set **maximum number of parallel project builds** = 1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue and I uninstalled SF SDK and VS tooling and installed latest version and it worked fine.

Here is the link to get latest SDK and VS tooling.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the SF cluster just gets into fritz and the only way is to Reset Local Cluster, and re-publish all applications. This usually happens after you install new SDK via Web Platform, but frankly it can happen anytime.